# HttpWebResponse returns with 5 numbers when searching through a string

Tags: c#, console, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;


/// <summary>
/// Fetches a Web Page
/// </summary>
class WebFetch
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // used to build entire input
    StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();

    // used on each read operation
    byte[]        buf = new byte[8192];

    // prepare the web page we will be asking for
    HttpWebRequest  request  = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("http://www.nbcwashington.com/weather/school-closings/");

    // execute the request
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
        request.GetResponse();

    // we will read data via the response stream
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    string tempString = null;
    int    count      = 0;

    do
    {
        // fill the buffer with data
        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

        // make sure we read some data
        if (count != 0)
        {
            // translate from bytes to ASCII text
            tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

            // continue building the string
            sb.Append(tempString);
        }
    }
    while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

    // print out page source
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    Console.Clear ();

    string output = sb.ToString();
    string searchForThis = "Open";
    int firstCharacter = output.IndexOf(searchForThis);
    Console.WriteLine(output.IndexOf(searchForThis));

    Console.ReadLine();


}
}
```

I am writing some code that will go to a website,grab some text,and paste it into the console vie HttpWebResponse, but when I use IndexOf() it returns 5 numbers something like "22452". Yes I know this code is probably pretty sloppy but i'm just starting. Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) IndexOf method:

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified
>   string in this instance.
>
> Return Value Type: System.Int32
>
> The zero-based index position of value if that string is found, or -1
>   if it is not. If value is String.Empty, the return value is 0.

So this `22452` is the index position of the first occurence of the `Open` in the output string variable.

Also, why you are using `Stream` if you could use StreamReader? Stream is an abstract class with no particular implimentation of its useful methods.

You could just use this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;


/// <summary>
/// Fetches a Web Page
/// </summary>
class WebFetch
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.nbcwashington.com/weather/school-closings/");

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream rawStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        string resOutput = String.Empty();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rawStream))
        {
            resOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(resOutput);
        Console.Clear();

        string searchForThis = "Open";
        int firstCharacter = resOutput.IndexOf(searchForThis);
        Console.WriteLine(resOutput.IndexOf(searchForThis))
        Console.ReadLine();
        response.Close();
    }
}
```